# How to send a CAN-message in CANoe 10 in one network to an another network?

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to send a message from one network to trigger an event on an another network in CANoe. They have different dbcs.

I've tried it with output(CAN.MessageName). Unfortunately it didn't work.
"'CAN' does not contain this member variable.  " is the error CANoe gave me.

Kind regards for helping me.

Comment: `output` is the way to go. Make sure your node is attached to both networks in the simulation setup. If you still have problems, you should show your code and potentially message definitions here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, today I added my node as a Gateway, so its possible to read both networks. But you are right, output was the way to go.